# How do I get the date of 31 days ago?

Tags: java, jodatime

How can I get `x` which should be 31 days before `current_date`?

```
x(date)___________________________current_date
                       31
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just subtract 31 days. For example:

```
LocalDate current = new LocalDate(2015, 6, 19);
LocalDate x = current.minusDays(31); // 2015-05-19
```

To *get* the current date, you could use:

```
LocalDate current = new LocalDate(); // Default time zone
```

or

```
LocalDate current = new LocalDate(zone); // Some specific zone
```

Or you may want to create your own "clock" representation which is able to give you the current `Instant`, in which case you'd use:

```
LocalDate current = clock.getCurrentInstant().toDateTime(zone).toLocalDate();
```

(That lets you use dependency injection to write simpler unit tests with a fake clock.)

Answer (score 6):

You can try this:

```
LocalDate current = new LocalDate();//Constructs an instance set to the current local time evaluated using ISO chronology in the default zone.
LocalDate x = current.minusDays(31);
```

Or otherwise you can try:

```
LocalDate current = LocalDate.now();//Obtains a LocalDate set to the current system millisecond time using ISOChronology in the default time zone
LocalDate x = current.minusDays(31);
```

Comment: Thank you Krishanthy Mohanachandran!

Answer (score 1):

You can used JODA API if you want, its very advance and useful features:

```
String DATE_PATTERN = "dd/MM/yyyy";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(DATE_PATTERN);
String systemDate = formatter.print(DateTime.now());
System.out.println("Current Date : " + systemDate);
String newDate = formatter.print(DateTime.now().minusDays(31));
System.out.println("Date 31 days ago : " + newDate);
```

Output:
Current Date : 19/06/2015

Date 31 days ago : 19/05/2015